# JavaScript Cookie Assist

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm having a terrible time trying to understand how cookies work in JavaScript.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Write out a Cookie called "Library" and set the expiration date for 21 days and
use an alert to let the user know the cookie was created

Redirect the user to another page "blah.html" if no errors occur (username or password left blank on a form) and post a message to the effect of "Welcome, " + username "!";. If error occurs, redirect to blah2.html and alert the user of the error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

my cookie code:

```
function writeCookie() {
  if (document.myForm.username.value == "") {
    alert("You did not enter a user name!");
    window.location.href. = "home.html";
  } else if (document.myForm.pwd.value == "") {
    alert("You did not enter a password!");
    window.location.href = "home.html";
  } else
    cookieValue = escape(document.myForm.username.value) + ";";
  document.cookie = "name=" + cookieValue;
  alert("Setting Cookies: " + "name=" + cookieValue);
  window.location.href = "private.html";

}

function getCookie() {
  var userWelcome = document.cookie;
}
```

my html code:

```
<p> Welcome to the Login Screen. To continue, please enter your username and password</p>

<form name="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend><b>User Information</b></legend><br>
    <label for="username">User Name:</label>
    <input name="username" size="20" maxlength="20" type="text">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input name="pwd" size="25" maxlength="25" type="password">
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
      <input type="Submit" value="Login" id="login" onclick="createCookie
    ();">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input value="Reset" type="reset"></center>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework

Comment: You have a syntax error here: `window.location.href. = "home.html";` The `.` after `href` is a mistake.

Comment: Your question says you want to create a cookie named `Location`, but your code creates a cookie named `name`. Also, the name of the function is `writeCookie()`, but the HTML calls `createCookie()`.

Answer (score 0):

So I moved some stuff around and cleaned up the error.

there was an error on this line: `window.location.href.` 
it should be : `window.location.href`

```
<script>
function writeCookie(){
try{
if(document.myForm.username.value == ""){
    alert("You did not enter a user name!");
    return false;
  } else if(document.myForm.pwd.value == ""){
    alert("You did not enter a password!");
    return false;
  } else {
    cookieValue = escape(document.myForm.username.value) +";";
    document.cookie = "name=" + cookieValue;
    alert("Setting Cookies: " + "name=" + cookieValue);    
    window.location.href = "private.html";
  }
} catch(e){alert(e); return false;}
}

function getCookie(){
var userWelcome = document.cookie;
}
</script>

<p> Welcome to the Login Screen. To continue, please enter your username and password</p>

<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return writeCookie()" action="post">

<fieldset>
<legend><b>User Information</b></legend><br>
<label for="username">User Name:</label>
<input name="username" size="20" maxlength="20" type="text">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="pwd">Password:</label>
<input name="pwd" size="25" maxlength="25" type="password">
<br>
<br>
```

I made it use the onsubmit action of the form, and it will return false if the user didn't enter in a username and password instead of the redirect. (I'm assuming that your redirecting it to the same page).  Currently, your code also does set the cookie value after I removed the error.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrnoaku1/19/) to show it working.

To retrieve the cookie simply do

```
    var cookie = document.cookie; 

    var name = cookie.split('=')[1];
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, now how would I go about getting the cookie to display the username on the other page like (Hello, User!)

Comment: if it's on the same domain, you should be able to do 

    var cookie = document.cookie; 
    
    var name = cookie.split('=')[1]